# How do I resolve '@echo' is not a recognized command

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've implemented Scott Hanselman's method for keeping up with a dev/qa/prod version of web.config:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=93bfa4b3-44cd-4681-b70e-f4a2b0386466

For some reason when I compile my project I get this error message in my output window.
 Any ideas?

```
------ Build started: Project: ABC.Flims.Web, Configuration: Development Any CPU ------
"C:\Projects\ballyhoo-trunk\src\ABC.Flims.Web\scripts/copyifnewer.bat" "C:\Projects\ballyhoo-trunk\src\ABC.Flims.Web\web.config.Development" "C:\Projects\ballyhoo-trunk\src\ABC.Flims.Web\web.config"
'∩╗┐@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is the script file:

```
@echo off
echo Comparing two files: %1 with %2

if not exist %1 goto File1NotFound
if not exist %2 goto File2NotFound

fc %1 %2 
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO NoCopy

echo Files are not the same.  Copying %1 over %2
copy %1 %2 /y & goto END

:NoCopy
echo Files are the same.  Did nothing
goto END

:File1NotFound
echo %1 not found.
goto END

:File2NotFound
copy %1 %2 /y
goto END

:END
echo Done.
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The file is probably Unicode encoded and has a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the start that is throwing off the batch processor.

Save it as an ASCII file and you should be OK. You can do this in `notepad` - select `Save As...` from the `File` menu and ensure that the `Encoding` dropdown is set to `ANSI`.

Comment: This issue solved an Azure startup issue I was working on. The .cmd file I was using was created as UTF-8 and not ANSI. Changing it in the manner you suggested solved the problem.

Comment: Too bad that visual studio has utf-8 as default and I need to revert to notepad(++) in order to save as ansi...

Comment: @JPHellemons - you can save with a different encoding directly in Visual Studio. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx

Comment: I get the default save as dialog in vs2017 (community edition) though thanks for your effort! :)

Comment: Thank you! Because of the bold font on msdn, I was looking for "Advanced Save Options" instead of the drop down. The screenshot helped a lot. Msdn could use your screenshot ;) or make the **drop-down button next to the Save** bold

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled upon a similar issue. Found that within visual studio, if you open your *.bat file, you can choose File -> Advanced Save Options. From the drop-down menu under encoding, select 'US-ASCII - Codepage 20127'

Comment: [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx) and [SuperUser Q and A](https://superuser.com/questions/601282/%CC%81-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) might prove useful.

Answer (score 5):

A file named echo.

```
P:\>echo.


P:\>dir /b echo
File Not Found

P:\>echo echo >echo

P:\>dir /b echo
echo

P:\>echo.
'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

P:\>del echo

P:\>dir /b echo
File Not Found

P:\>echo.


P:\>
```

An echo in current folder or in the path will cause this.

/echo

Comment: Correct, normally "echo." works to output a blank line in a series of echo commands. However if (in my case through testing redirection and making a typo) a file exists in the directory named "echo" then "echo." is no longer processed as a call to echo with an empty parameter (blank line), it is processed as a call to the local "echo" file. Thanks, this helped me find the problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think your file is Unicode encoded and needs to be ascii.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: check for a file "echo." in the same folder as the batch script. When there, delete it.

```
C:\Scripts>echo.

'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Scripts>dir echo*.*

 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 46CF-DC0A

 Directory of C:\Scripts

11/04/2022  06:50 AM                 0 echo
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  686,672,957,440 bytes free

C:\Scripts>del echo.

C:\Scripts>dir echo*.*

 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 46CF-DC0A

 Directory of C:\Scripts

File Not Found

C:\Scripts>echo.


C:\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\echo ==> some times there is a file which is called "echo" without extension. and it caused this error : 'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,