# Unable to delete a file from a simple batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that contains this code:

```
del /F /S /Q /A "debug.properties"
del /F /S /Q /A "context/security/preauth/projectid-source/header/projectid-source.xml"
del /F /S /Q /A "context/compatibility/readme.txt"
del /F /S /Q /A "archived_logs"
del /F /S /Q /A "ai-license-add-in-IrsProjectManagement.bin"
del /F /S /Q /A "context/security/preauth/projectid-source/header/projectid-source.properties"
del /F /S /Q /A "debug.properties.DSPROD"
del /F /S /Q /A "context/security/preauth/projectid-source/header"
```

When I execute the batch from the command line I get the error:
   " 'd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

It works fine when I execute the del statement directly from the command line.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Which line gives you the error? What's the name of your batch file?

Comment: The name of the file is test_1b.bat and the error takes place on the first line of the file. When I comment out the first line (REM) I get the message "'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...'

Comment: Funny behavior. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159534/), does it help you fix your problem?

Comment: What editor are you using to create the batch file?  This sounds like a Unicode issue.  Can you try the following `type test_1b.bat > test_1b_ascii.bat` and see if the new batch file works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file is obviously saved as [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) encoded file without a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) (BOM).

Text editors usually indicate the encoding of a file somewhere. For example text editor UltraEdit indicates the encoding for active file at bottom in status bar.

This batch file UTF-16 encoded without BOM starts in binary with the bytes

```
00000000h: 64 00 65 00 6C 00 20 00 2F 00 46 00 20 00 2F 00 ; d.e.l. ./.F. ./.
00000010h: 53 00 20 00 2F 00 51 00 20 00 2F 00 41 00 20 00 ; S. ./.Q. ./.A. .
00000020h: 22 00 64 00 65 00 62 00 75 00 67 00 2E 00 70 00 ; ".d.e.b.u.g...p.
00000030h: 72 00 6F 00 70 00 65 00 72 00 74 00 69 00 65 00 ; r.o.p.e.r.t.i.e.
00000040h: 73 00 22 00 0D 00 0A                            ; s."....
```

As the NULL byte is interpreted as end of string by **cmd.exe**, the command to run is just **d** which is an unknown command.

Convert the file from UTF-16 to ASCII in text editor (option on Save As) or with

```
type test_1b.bat > test_1b_ascii.bat
```

as suggested by [Ryan Bemrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821878/ryan-bemrose) and the batch file will start working.

Batch files are usually in North American and Western European countries "ASCII" files using an OEM code page like [code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (OEM multilingual Latin I) or [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (OEM US) and not code page [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as used usually for single byte encoded text files. The code page to use for a batch file depends on local settings for non Unicode files in console. The code page does not matter if just characters with a code value smaller 128 are used in batch file, i.e. the batch file is a real [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) file.