# Not recognized command everytime in the first line of a code

Tags: batch-file, command, line

I have a problem with my BATCH file...
Whatever is written on the first line, it says: [command] is not a command.

Like so:

```
@ECHO OFF
```

I get this output:

> [C:\folder (path)]>´╗┐@ECHO OFF
>
> ´╗┐@ECHO is not a command

It does the same even in a clear batch file(nothing except @ECHO OFF in it). Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve '@echo' is not a recognized command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337445/how-do-i-resolve-echo-is-not-a-recognized-command)

Comment: other duplicates: [Batch file not running due to weird symbols at the start of the line](https://superuser.com/q/1084067/241386), [Weird characters (´╗┐) at the start of a batch file](https://superuser.com/q/769601/241386), [Not recognized command everytime in the first line of a code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28836113/995714)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing the BOM (Byte Order Mark) of the file, probably utf-8 encoded. Open with an editor and save the file with ANSI encoding.

Comment: Oh thank you! I had that problem a hellotta times tho.

Comment: Also helpful to reference a text editor which allows you to show special characters and encoding.  For example, Notepad ++ because Notepad++ can show all characters in a file.  Otherwise, paste the text into Windows Notepad and save AS TXT then re-try.